# Using update panel in AJAX a good practice in asp.net?

Tags: asp.net, ajax

Using update panel in AJAX a good practice in asp.net ??? ... or one should code himself for AJAX for each and every control using HTTP-Object ? In which scenarios are the above two strategies used ???

Comment: Remember to accept an answer if you felt it was helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Update Panel is a good thing in that it allows the developer to code AJAX very simply.  It has a lot of overhead, though, and I would not recommend it as a solution in most (if not all) cases.

Look into [ASP.Net AJAX](http://www.asp.net/ajax/) for a good way to get started using AJAX.  Its fairly simple, robust, and flexible.  (It doesn't prevent you from using the update panel either).